# Ambiguous method call without optional parameters

Tags: c#

I have a class with two constructors:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(string bar = "hello"){
    }

    public Foo(string bar = "hello", string barrier = "world"){
    }
}
```

Now, when I want to call the constructor with 1 parameter, I can call:

```
new Foo();
```

But I'm getting an ambiguous reference error because Visual Studio doesn't know which constructor I want to use. How can I specify which constructor I want without passing parameters?

Comment: Don't create ambiguous constructors like this in the first place.

Comment: just make the second constructor the default and leave the first or use paramarray args type deal.  Like @Servy said, this isn't good practice anyway so I would avoid situations like this for the sake of writing good code if nothing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve the ambiguity, you should make the second method have a required parameter:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(string bar = "hello"){
    }

    public Foo(string bar, string barrier = "world"){
    }
}
```

That is the only way to make the method resolution deterministic.

But as noted already, that default parameter is useless, since in any other case it will drop to the second constructor. A better option is to drop the first constructor, but if that works out depends on the implementation inside:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(string bar = "hello", string barrier = "world"){
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this still ambiguous if you call it with a single string?

Comment: No, the first constructor then prevails.

Comment: @tkausl Technically, no, the first constructor wins in that case (it's a "better" match in that situation, so there's no ambiguity), but it's still a bad idea as it's highly confusing to any caller.

Comment: Well then I don't see the point in having a default for the second argument given this default will never be used as calling it with one argument always calls the first constructor. I'd just remove the first constructor completely

Comment: Not if adding barrier does something more than the first constructor @tkausl

Comment: @PatrickHofman It's not going to be obvious to most people which is called, as is evidenced by all of the people that read this answer and thought it was ambiguous.

Comment: @PatrickHofman There's still no point in it having a default value.  The default value isn't ever going to be used, even if the parameter is.

Comment: @Servy Now I get what you mean. Thanks. Updated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No idea why you got downvoted, as it clearly answers my question "Can I call this constructor".

Comment: Well, I do understand in retrospect.

Comment: There actually is another solution: Create a default ctor as follows: `public Foo(): this("Hello"){}`

Comment: @ohyeah It *doesn't* answer your question.  The question asks how to specify which constructor is called, this changes the code to not have ambiguous constructors (in the worst way possible).  If want to know how to make the constructors not be ambiguous (which isn't what you asked) this is not a good way to do it, and if you *can't* change the constructors, this doesn't answer the question.  Either way it's not a good answer.

Answer (score 4):

The point of default values is to reduce the number of methods, just have

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(string bar = "hello", string barrier = "world"){
    }
}
```

and set whatever defaults you need for the call, Foo is a single class that should handle all the defaults otherwise its seems it's being used for different purposes

Answer (score 0):

Just make one method that checks both params for string.isNullOrEmpty

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    testme("DD", "jj");
    Console.ReadLine();
}


public static void testme(string d="", string s = "")
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(d) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
        return;
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(d))
        Console.Write(s);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        Console.Write(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved quite simply like this, using just one constructor. I've added some extra code to faciliate a simple demonstration:

```
public class Foo
{
    private string _bar;
    private string _barrier;
    
    public Foo(string bar = "hello", string barrier = "world"){
        _bar = bar;
        _barrier = barrier;
    }
    
    public void show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("_bar = " + _bar + " , _barrier = " + _barrier);
    }
}
```

Then all of these combinations are valid...

```
Foo a = new Foo();
a.show();
Foo b = new Foo("b");
b.show();
Foo c = new Foo(barrier: "c");
c.show();
Foo d = new Foo("d", "e");
d.show();
```

...and result in the following output:

> _bar = hello , _barrier = world
>
> _bar = b , _barrier = world
>
> _bar = hello , _barrier = c
>
> _bar = d , _barrier = e

Comment: The parameterless constructor is useless.

Comment: Now your answer is just the same as Marks, and mine.

Comment: @PatrickHofman yours involves 2 constructors instead of 1, so not quite the same approach. I agree it's basically the same as Mark's now, although it wasn't the original intention. Mine provides a proof ofconcept as well, which I hope might aid understanding if people are struggling with the concept.

Comment: No, I said that is necessary to solve the compiler error. The solution is in the following text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need public constructors? Try something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        var person = Person.FromName ();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    private Person (string name, string surname) { }

    public static Person FromName (string name = "John") => new Person (name, "Smith");

    public static Person FromFullName (string name = "John", string surname = "Smith") => new Person (name, surname);
}
```

Of course `Person` class is just an example (bad example :P) but you should get the idea.